# Pandas - How to match up rows if they contain the same value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 4 columns: 'age_1', 'name_1', 'age_2' and 'name_2'.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=[0, 4, 6, 9],
                  data={'age_1': [18, np.nan, 12, np.nan],
                        'name_1': ['Fred', np.nan, 'Harry', np.nan],
                        'age_2': [np.nan, 34, np.nan, 45],
                        'name_2': [np.nan, 'Jim', np.nan, 'Fred']})
```

Output

```
    age_1   name_1  age_2   name_2
0   18.0    Fred    NaN     NaN
4   NaN     NaN     34.0    Jim
6   12.0    Harry   NaN     NaN
9   NaN     NaN     45.0    Fred
```

All names appear twice (once in name_1 and once in name_2) I want to put the rows together where name_1 and name_2 have the same item in. For example from the snippet above, i want it to put the first and last row together like this:

```
    age_1   name_1  age_2   name_2
0   18.0    Fred    45.0    Fred
```

Any help would be great

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can split the dataframe into two parts and join them using merge. since the join columns `name_1` & `name_2` have nulls, you have to drop the nulls first.

```
l1 = ['age_1', 'name_1']
l2 = ['age_2', 'name_2']

df[l1].dropna().merge(df[l2].dropna(), left_on='name_1', right_on='name_2')

#outputs:
   age_1 name_1  age_2 name_2
0   18.0   Fred   45.0   Fred
```

Answer (score 0):

If `df` is your dataframe:

```
df[["age_1", "name_1"]].dropna(how="all").join(df[["name_2", "age_2"]].dropna(how="all").set_index("name_2")[["age_2"]], on="name_1")
```

Will give you approximately what you're looking for (the name will not be repeated as in your example, since it's the key that's being joined on, it will appear just once).

Note this is a left join, any `name_2`s that do not have corresponding `name_1`s will be thrown away (however, `name_1`s with no corresponding `name_2`, like `Harry`, will remain). If you want to keep those `name_2`s, just add `how="outer"` as as keyword argument to the join method. If you're sure that all names will always appear twice, then it won't matter.

If a `name_1` has multiple `name_2`s, the row will be repeated to accomodate as many `name_2`s as it has. Again, if each name appears exactly twice (exactly once in the `name_1` column and exactly once in the `name_2` column), this won't matter. I would add a check for that like this:

```
# check that there are no repeats
for col in ("name_1", "name_2"):
    assert df[col].dropna().nunique() == df[col].dropna().shape[0]

# check that all `name_1`s have corresponding `name_2`s
assert set(df["name_1"].dropna()) == set(df["name_2"].dropna())
```

Edited: to add dropna's as suggest in comments

Comment: what if a name appears more than twice?

Comment: What happens if I add columns to my data frame (df) will the above code need to change?

Comment: you should add a `dropna` either during the merge as I have done or after the merge.

Answer (score 0):

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'age_1':[18,'',12,''],'name_1':['Fred','','Harry',''],'age_2':['',34,'',45],'name_2':['','Jim','','Fred']})
df1=df[['age_1','name_1']]
df2=df[['age_2','name_2']]
df_new=df1.merge(df2,how='left',left_on='name_1',right_on='name_2' )
df_new=df_new.replace('',np.nan)
df_new.dropna(how='any',inplace =True)
df_new
```

Output

```
   age_1    name_1  age_2   name_2
0   18.0    Fred    45.0    Fred
```